DataprocPySparkBatchOp - Pass component's output to runtime_config_properties as dictionary
I am creating a Dataproc batch job from VertexAI pipeline.
    get_stores_and_discount_data = (DataprocPySparkBatchOp(
    project=PROJECT_ID,
    location=REGION,
    batch_id=f"dataproc-job-{file_date}",
    main_python_file_uri=get_data_file,
    python_file_uris=[
        os.path.join("gs://", DEPS_BUCKET, DEPENDENCY_PATH, "src.zip")
    ],
    file_uris=[
        os.path.join(
            "gs://",
            DEPS_BUCKET,
            DEPENDENCY_PATH,
            "settings.toml",
        )
    ],
    subnetwork_uri=SUBNETWORK_URI,
    container_image=PROMO_SPARK_DATAPROC_IMAGE,
    runtime_config_version=RUNTIME_CONFIG_VERSION,
    service_account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
    spark_history_dataproc_cluster=HISTORY_SERVER_CLUSTER,
    runtime_config_properties=SPARK_PROPERTIES_MEDIUM,
    labels=SPARK_LABELS,
    ).set_display_name("get-data").after(date_task)
)

For runtime_config_properties=SPARK_PROPERTIES_MEDIUM, I want to use an environment variable that is an output of a component. When I try, it throws an error.
Error

ValueError: Value must be one of the following types: str, int, float, bool, dict, and list. Got: "{{channel:task=generate-date;name=curr_timestamp;type=String;}}" of type "<class 'kfp.dsl.pipeline_channel.PipelineParameterChannel'>".

CURR_TIMESTAMP = date_task.outputs["curr_timestamp"]
SPARK_PROPERTIES_MEDIUM["spark.dataproc.driverEnv.REPORTING_TIMESTAMP"] = CURR_TIMESTAMP

The component code looks this:
@component(base_image="python:3.9-slim")
def generate_date() -> NamedTuple('Output', [("file_date", str), ('curr_timestamp', str)]):
    """
    Generates the current date and time in the format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.

    Returns:
        str: A string representing the current date and time.
    """
    from datetime import datetime
    dt = datetime.today()
    file_date = dt.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    curr_timestamp = dt.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H:%m:%S")
    return (file_date, curr_timestamp)



How to get this fixed?

Hi @Tom, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCPsupport case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.
